# CFBundleDisplayName returns 'null'

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, xcode5, info-plist

I'm trying to get app name to use as the NavController title, but whatever I do I can't get CFBundleDisplayName value. It returns 'null'.

this is the code I'm using

```
[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary][@"CFBundleDisplayName"]
```

Checked bundles = there is one only.
Xcode5 / dev target is iOS5. 
I haven't checked on a device though. Using Simulator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Try this code to get app name

```
   NSString *appName =      [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleNameKey];
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift extension, tested with iOS 9:

```
extension UIApplication {

    static var applicationName: String {
        let mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        let key = String(kCFBundleNameKey)
        let value = mainBundle.objectForInfoDictionaryKey(key) as? String
        return value ?? ""
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Goto project setting & set display name, Then you can check.